# Is it possible to listen for UDP in Azure Function

Tags: azure, udp, azure-functions

Is it possible to get an incoming UDP packet through to an Azure Function? I'm evaluating possibilities for a testing system that would emulate a short exchange of an IoT type device.

The easiest would be to have an Azure Function triggerable with HTTP, and the function would send and receive few UDP packets. The sending part shouldn't be a problem, but is there a way to get an incoming UDP packet routed to a Azure function instance? I would imagine not, but haven't been able to find any information.

Secondary method would be to have an Azure Function triggerable by a UDP packet, but that's not possible either with the triggers provided, but there could a way to use some other Azure component, maybe with IoT Hub and/or VNet? I'm not terribly knowledgeable about all the possibilities and would appreciate some insight.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the answer is no. At this moment, App Service (which hosts Functions) has some limitations which restricts to TCP 80/443.

The alternatives: Virtual Machine / the old cloud services (worker role) / Service Fabric / AKS

Comment: I was afraid this would be the case - thanks for your input.